# linux copy files recursive with file's suffix name only

Tags: shell

`cp` is the Linux command for copying files with support of recursively mode with `cp -a <from> <to>`

How about if I want to copy recursively with `-a`, and only `*.c *.h` such as kernel source.

Is there any linux commands that can achieve this?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You should provide example of what you exactly are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. You should provide example of what you exactly are trying to achieve.

`cp` can copy recursively via `-r` or `-R` or `--recursive` flags

`-a` in `cp`:

```
       -a, --archive
              same as -dR --preserve=all
```

to copy files from one directory with specific ext:

```
cp -r *.c destination/
cp -r fromcomefolder/*.h destination/
```

If you however need to find recursively all `*.c` files, from different source folders, and then copy them, `cp` is not your best friend. Or at least you will need other helper programs.